# IDEA start a non-existing templates?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, spring-mvc

have problem with IDEA?

I create new Spring Boot project, with dependency Spring Web, Spring Security, Spring JPA and others

Create two simple class

1. main class
2. Controller Class

@Controller
public class {

```
@GetMapping("")
public String Home() {
    return "homes";
}
```

}

And simple templates "homes.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home Code Java</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome to home JVM</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

WHY MY IDEA START THIS???   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dnn-IKkpaBeouyqnGU13YLf1GBPVd_jQ?usp=sharing
WHAT IS IT ???? in this link different template, not my!
but port is my, localhost 9092/
this port is  - localhost 9092/login?  where did login come from with this templates ?

my link in @GetMapping (""), not (/login)

PLS HELP !

in properties port=9092

Comment: If I recall correctly, Spring Boot tries to have sensible default configurations - since you are adding Spring Security, I am going to guess the configuration for it has an endpoint created that listens to `/login` -

Comment: I add Spring Boot Security only in pom.xml. I do not create security configuration!

Comment: You did not but the security dependency (which means you add a full .jar file into your project) does come with default configurations

Comment: @blurfus tnx you

Answer (score 2):

You have added spring security dependency in your pom.xml and that is the reason spring is securing all the endpoints by default.

Either remove the dependency or configure it to allow access to wanted endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because of Adding the dependencies of Spring Security to you pom.xml, which automatically securing the endpoints by default.

try removing this dependency or configure it to allow access to the endpoint you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).